# Solving Project Euler #1

Tags: c#

The problem in project Euler says:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

When I test it with the numbers < 10, it calculates 23, but when I try it with 1000, it gives the wrong answer. Please help :)

Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //Initialisation
            Console.WriteLine ("==============================");
            Console.WriteLine ("Project Euler - Problem 1 - Multiples of 3 and 5 - Test");
            Console.WriteLine ("Initialising");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch ();
            stopwatch.Start ();
            Console.WriteLine ("==============================");

            HashSet<int> list = new HashSet<int> (); //Creates a list

            int sum = 0;

            //Add every multiple of 3 to the list
            for (int x = 3; x < 10; x = x + 3) {
                list.Add (x); 
            }

            //Add every multiple of 5 to the list
            for (int y = 5; y < 10; y = y + 5) {
                list.Add (y);
            }

            //Remove every duplicate from the list
            for (int z = 15; z <= 1000; z = z +15) {
                list.Remove (z);
            }

            foreach (int x in list) {
                sum = sum + x;
            }

            //Termination
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            Console.WriteLine ("==============================");
            stopwatch.Stop ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine ("==============================");
            Console.WriteLine ("Sum: " + sum);
            Console.WriteLine ("==============================");
            Console.WriteLine ("Terminating");
            Console.WriteLine ("==============================");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your `x < 10;` to `x < 1000;` and `y < 10` to `y < 1000` and remove the third for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `HashSet`.

> HashSet is an unordered collection containing unique elements

It doesn't store duplicate entries. You don't need to remove it.

Just remove your 3rd `for loop`.

Comment: So, hashset automatically removes duplicates?

Comment: It doesn't add duplicate entries.

Comment: Also he needs to change his `x < 10;` to `x < 1000;` and `y < 10;` to `y < 1000;`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple for loops you could also have one and use the modulus operator. This will void the duplicates you are adding.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        // Add to list
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the calculation speed is about the same, tyvm!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove multiples of `15`:

```
const int N = 1000;

//Add every multiple of 3 to the list
for (int x = 3; x < N; x += 3) {
     list.Add(x); 
}

//Add every multiple of 5 to the list
for (int y = 5; y < N; y += 5) {
    list.Add(y);
}

int sum = list.Sum();
```

Comment: but why did you add a const N?

Comment: @AlexanderAmeye (1) To avoid *magic* numbers in the code. (2) To be able easily change the upper bound for all loops.